# How to submit the multiple rows form data with a single submit in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Here is my code.
I made a form with multiple rows which will be updated in a single submit.
I searched in forums, but didn't find the exact answer.

```
<form method='POST' action='demo24.php'>
  <table  width="500px" height="500px">
    <tr><th>SETNAME</th><th>POST</th></tr>
    <?php
      $query = "SELECT name,setid FROM `set` LIMIT 0 ,10";
      $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()."[".$query."]");
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
        $output .='<tr><td><input type="text" value="'.$row['name'].' '.$row['setid'].'" name="name'.$row['setid'].'">'.$row['name'].'</td><td><input type="checkbox" value="'.$row['setid'].'" name="setid"></td></tr>';
      }  

      echo $output;
    ?>


    </td><td><input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'/></td></tr>
  </table>        
</form>
```

Comment: `metho=` != `method=""` (typo)

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can use something like `name[]` in multiple input fields to send an array to the server:

```
<input type="text" name="row[]" />
<input type="text" name="row[]" />
```

On the server side `$_POST['row']` will look like this:

```
Array (
  [0] => first_input,
  [1] => second_input
)
```

You can do this for all fields (`id`, `row`, etc.) and then loop through `$_POST['id']` etc. to get all entries back together. Be sure to validate enough, i.e. make sure that those fields are indeed arrays, that all are of the same size, etc.

---

The MySQL family of PHP is deprecated and support thereof will disappear. Please look into [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) to execute SQL code instead.

Answer (score 0):

If your form method as 'post' then you can use this code :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   $query = "SELECT name,setid FROM `set` LIMIT 0 ,10";
   $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()."[".$query."]");
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
      $id = $row['setid'];
      $name = $_POST['name'.$id];
     //here will be you update code. set value will be $name and update where setid = $id
   }
}
```